# How to pass variables to PHP to Python function?

Tags: php, python, wxpython

I have the code in PHP side:

```
function apiTest($arga){
if (!isset($arga['name'])) {
   printf("Missing required parameter 'name'\n");
   return RET_PARAMSMISSING;
}

$retVal = 'testing';
printf("JSON:\n%s",json_wrapper($retVal)
return RET_NOERROR;
}

case 'testing':
    $retval = apiTest($arga);
    break;
```

In Browser running this script locahost/testing.php. Here is printing correctly:

```
TIDBITS API
C:/wamp/www/testing.php running @ Sat, 10 Dec 2016 14:08:06
Executing function 'Test'
JSON:
testing

RETURN: 0
```

Here is json_wrapper printing the output correctly.

This Json_wrapper value how to pass to python function.
I have tried using the below code, but it's not working.

```
def inventory(self, **kwargs):
return self.tidbitsapi('testing')
```

I need to get the PHP variable to python side and perform some operation and once pass to return value true/false to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a system call:

from php:

```
system('C:/pythonXX/python.exe pathToPythonModule.py "' . arg . '"')
```

from python:

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        varFromPhp = sys.argv[2]
        print(varFromPhp)
    else: print("Didn't get parameter")
```